# SIP REGISTER failed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sip, voip

I'm attempting to create a small VoIP Client in Visual Studio 2012.
i'm trying to send a REGISTER SIP message from a pc to an AsteriskNOW PBX via UDP. The devices are the following:

```
IP PBX AsteriskNOW: 192.168.1.37
PC that sends REGISTER message: 192.168.1.104
SIP account username: 117
SIP account password: abcd1234
```

so, the REGISTER message i'm trying to send is the following:

```
REGISTER sip:192.168.1.37 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.104:5060;branch=z9hG4bK213760691;rport
From: <sip:117@192.168.1.37>;tag=1270517038
To: <sip:117@192.168.1.37>
Call-ID: 1808066864-5060-1@BJC.BGI.B.D
CSeq: 2001 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:117@192.168.1.104:5060>;reg-id=1;
+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-AABBCCDDEEFF>"
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Grandstream GXP1165 1.0.6.7
Supported: path
Expires: 3600
Allow: INVITE, ACK, OPTIONS, CANCEL, BYE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, REFER, 
UPDATE, MESSAGE
Content-Length: 0
```

of course, at the line

```
+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-AABBCCDDEEFF>"
```

there's the PC,s Network adapter MAC, instead of "AABBCCDDEEFF".
However, when I try to send the message, i get the following response from the server:

```
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
192.168.1.104:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.1.104;branch=z9hG4bK213760691
Call-ID: 1808066864-5060-1@BJC.BGI.B.D
From: <sip:117@192.168.1.37>;tag=1270517038
To: <sip:117@192.168.1.37>;tag=z9hG4bK2137606914
CSeq: 2001 REGISTER
WWW-Authenticate: Digest
realm="asterisk",nonce="1428402653/99967d603c38695f1c328332db91a43b",
opaque="416e7e1767513798",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: FPBX-AsteriskNOW-12.0.43(13.0.1)
Content-Length:  0
```

what can be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: This is normal, you send a REGISTER the server says you're unauthorized, and sends you back the WWW-Authenticate header that you need to use to compute your credentials. I.e. you are supposed to authenticate yourself - if you're writing your own SIP client you'll need to read the SIP specification carefully and follow/implement the full SIP protocol.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I read lots of documents about SIP protocol, but no one explain this specific step in details... any suggestion on what I should search and/or any link i can try with?

Comment: I found an explanation on Wikipedia at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication   it says that i should calculate the MD5 HA1 and HA2 then the response. HA1=MD5(username:realm:password) and this is clear, but what about HA2=MD5(method:digestURI)? where can i get the "method" and "digestURI" variable?

Comment: Here's a C# example of the SIP authentication digest you should be able to work from http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#sipsorcery-core/SIPSorcery.SIP.Core/SIPAuthorisation/SIPAuthorisationDigest.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using the ozeki library to manage SIP messages
I found the library here

http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_179-windows-forms-softphone-vb-net-voip.html

Thank you!